# Using a string with variables as a function name

Tags: php, string, oop, quote

I would like to call the right function according to what the user did.

Here is my code :

```
$sFunction = $sAction.'_dispatch('.$sType.')';
$oMyObject->$sFunction;
```

$sAction and $sType are PHP variable that I've got using JS.
$sAction can be 'delete', 'edit', 'add' and $sType can be 'package', 'content' etc.

I think that I have a problem with my quotes, if you could explain why you put them here or not. This problem made me wondering if a parameter was sent as a name + value or just value.

NB : I've a PHP Notice "Undefined property" and this doesn't access my function in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre almost there, you just have things a bit mixed up.

```
$sFunction = $sAction.'_dispatch';
$oMyObject->$sFunction($sType);
```

should work.

Pass the parameter in on the call, not where you define the variable name.

Comment: This is so obvious.. I'll definitely think harder before asking next time, thank you for your answer and your help !